# I keep getting an error while running a form in the html page the points to another html page in eclipse

Tags: html, eclipse, tomcat, computer-science

I wrote this html code 
[Form.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9Hq9.png)

and it is supposed to go to the result page, but when I submit the form or press the link at the end, it doesn't open and I get 404 error after submitting.

P.S: It works perfectly by using "Notepad++" but not in Eclipse.

[Result.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mSd1.png)

Comment: What URL is being requested? Is it the right one? What's working correctly in Notepad++--it doesn't do anything with servers, does it?

Comment: yes. only simple html pages in both eclipse and Notpad